# Using If commands with nested lists

Tags: list-manipulation, random

been beating my head against a wall with this question: 2 people play a marble rolling game. 1 person gets 1 roll, the other gets 2 rolls. The person with the roll the closest distance to a certain object wins the game(max 2m from the object).

I've managed to get it working for 1 iteration, but now I need to create results for 12 plays of the game. So far I have got:

```
roll2 = Table[RandomReal[2, 3], 12]


 {{1.96851, 1.48356, 0.41756}, {1.64814, 0.0124319, 
      0.350543}, {1.75798, 1.52129, 0.206328}, {0.486459, 1.8329, 
      0.112136}, {0.0547005, 0.605605, 1.70465}...
```

**From these results, how do I create an if statement that: if the first element in each bracket is the smallest in the bracket, it will output "you win", and "you lose" otherwise.**

I've tried using map functions for this for example:

```
smallestroll2 = Map[TakeSmallest[1], roll2](*the smallest element in each bracket*)
```

and:

```
firstroll = Map[First, roll2](*the first element in each bracket*)
```

These inputs have been outputting what I want, but I can't figure out how to get them into an if statement. So, how would I get these into an if statement, or if there is an easier way, how would I do it. Thanks.

Comment: You can define a function `matchOutcome[matchResult_] := 
 If[First[#] == Min[#], "You win", "You lose"] &@matchResult` and then map it over `roll2`, i.e. `matchOutcome /@ roll2`.

Comment: @Natas Thanks, worked :)